# Can we swap out SQL Server with HBase?

Tags: sql-server, linq, elasticsearch, hbase, hadoop2

In a current application we use SQL Server.

The data flow consists of using TVPs for better-than-bulk-insert performance by passing in DataTables.

As part of the data addition process, old records are deleted based on date searches.

There are simple relationships created for user accounts, geographic data, etc.

FreeText searching is enabled in a datamart that is the primary source for accessed data.  Again, with data access there is logging in the db.

Data is accessed through a generic repository, Entity Framework and Linq commands.

I was thinking of using ElasticSearch for all of this, but in my recent reads of HBase, it looks like I can create tables and perform some of the same basic SQL commands as well as Linq queries.

The reason for this is that I would like to do some Hadoop work with this data in the future.

However for now I would like to know if using HBase is an option for currently replacing our current SQL implementation/usage? If so,  I will also be attempting to use the generic repository with HBase or whatever other faster (and less expensive/more free than SQL Server) database, and if possible with some big data analytics capabilities for the future.

I apologize if the information I have provided is not clear enough and will gladly clarify if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of linq or many other stuff you mentioned. but I can answer for **perform some of the same basic SQL commands in HBase**. There are no equivalent sql queries for Hbase. Hive is more similar to SQL stuff. Either its the way data is stored, queried and integration with Hadoop, Hive is the one. Hbase is for a different usage. Mostly for low latency, expecially if you query based on row key(primary key equivalent). The way data is stored is different(predominantly NoSql). So you have to redesign the structure of data which is already there in SQL server.
My answer is just the tip of the iceberg and to your point.You have the whole internet to get more analysis. happy learning

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about linq support either, but I have recently started using [Apache Phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org/) and I am very happy with it's support for SQL on top of HBase. Note that Phoenix is a Read/Write solution while several other HBase SQL engines are read only.

Comment: What kinds of searches are you running on HBase?  I am contemplating ElasticSearch instead for free text searches.  Thoughts?

Comment: I use it for time series data. If you're indexing text, ES is definitely the [preferred] way to go.